# ACF and PACF Plot

Tags: time-series, arima, model-selection, lags, acf-pacf

I am a first year stat student. We are tasked to create a SARIMA model from trial and error using ACF and PACF plot. Now here is my generated plot:

[image]

Now I am trying to understand the plot but I don't know what is the appropriate model I can build here. My guess is ARIMA(1,1,1)(1,1,0)[4], but I am doubtful it is right. Can someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: What is the frequency of your data?

Comment: it is a quarterly data so the frequency is 4